# What built-in exception to throw when expecting only one value but many are present

Tags: java, exception

I'd like to throw an exception in a method that is expecting a list that only has one element, and I'd like to throw an exception if the list has more than one.  I am trying to determine if there is an appropriate existing Java exception to throw for this case.  I tried eyeballing the list [here](http://wuhrr.wordpress.com/2007/11/22/java-exceptions-list/) but didn't see anything that jumped out as correct.

In this case I am calling a method of an object, with the expectation that the method is referencing said list as an attribute of the object. So I am actually not passing the array, nor an index as an argument.

(edited for clarification)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to imply that given input is not a valid one you should use `IllegalArgumentException` with a message stating the reason for the same.

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input specified has more elements then expected");
```

Or else you can have your own `Exception` which uniquely defines the condition.

Though I somehow feel since its the number of elements which is the reason for exception you can even use `IndexOutOfBoundsException` which makes sense in the given scenario.

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Expected size is 1, submitted input has size " + list.size());
```

Edit: As per comment

Given that list is not part of method call but belongs to the object whose method is invoked, in this case `list.size() > 1` signifies that object is not in a correct state and with that a customized version of `IllegalStateException` or `IllegalStateException` itself with a proper error message would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, I had thought about that, but in this case I am calling a method on an object, with the expectation that the method is referencing said list as an attribute of the object.  So I am actually not passing the array, nor an index as an argument, so I thought perhaps IllegalArgumentException didn't fit the bill.  Perhaps calling the method as I've defined it qualifies as an argument (or perhaps I need to rethink my method signatures).

Comment: @JoshDiehl: So, in fact, your question does not describe what you want to do? Please correct your question - including a small amount of code demonstrating the situation would be useful.

Comment: @JoshDiehl Your choices really do seem to be what mprabhat suggests: make your own, or use IllegalArgumentException (that being the closest).

Comment: After clarifying the question, it seems that both IllegalArgument... and IndexOut... don't quite fit the bill.  

IllegalState... seems the closet, although Javadocs state "Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation."  

Since timing isn't the issue here, I should probably create my own exception extended from IllegalState. (or re-architect this method and attribute!)

Comment: `IllegalStateException` _really_ appears like it's the wrong thing here.  It's usually used when you're making _repeated_ calls to methods on a _single_ object.  If the method is throwing an exception because the argument wasn't right, `IllegalArgumentException` is much more appropriate.

Comment: @LouisWasserman OP is not passing the list as an argument rather it is property of the object whose method is being called, in this case IllegalStateException or an extension makes it clear

Answer (score 3):

You could make your own exception and throw it.

```
public MyException extends Exception {
}

if(list.size() > 1) {
    throw new MyException("Expected only 1 element, found: " + list.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list is a field of the object on which you're invoking the method, then you could say that an object which has a list of the wrong size is in the wrong state, and so `IllegalStateException` would be appropriate.

But really, you should replace the list with a scalar field (`List<Foo>` becomes `Foo`), so that this situation cannot even arise.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw the erros in the method like this

```
public void someMethod(List<MyClass> myList) throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException {
    if (myList == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("myList parameter can't be null");
    if (myList.size() > 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("myList parameter must contain only 1 parameter");
    }
    //your code here...
}
```

It would be better to set the error messages in a properties file so you will just need to change the configuration to show the new message, no need to rewrite the error message by modifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the use case, so this answer may be off base, but I would suggest an AssertionError

```
List < T > answers ; // expection a list of size one
assert 1 == list . size ( ) : "The programmer expects that there will be one and only one answer"
/*
In development:  assertions enabled,
 If there are zero answers, the program will crash on the assertion.
 If there are multiple answers, the program will crash on the assertion.
 Only if there is exactly one answer will it proceed to the below line (and work correctly).
In production:  assertions disbled,
 If there are zero answers, the program will throw a RuntimeException on the below line.
 If there are multiple answers, the program will proceed to the below line (and appear to work).
 If there is only one answer, the program will proceed to the below line and wok correctly.
*/
T answer = answers . get ( 0 ) ;
```

Advantages of this approach over using `if` or`switch`

1. Some code coverage tools will want you to write unit tests for branches.
2. Branches add to the cyclomatic complexity.
3. Evaluations are nperformed only during development